# WxPython: GetFocusedItem() retornando item mesmo com nada focado

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, wxwidgets

Estou escrevendo uma interface com wxPython, mas me deparei com um problema até agora sem solução, mesmo olhando a documentação.

Eu tenho um ListCtrl com vários items que devem ser enviados à outro ListCtrl quando se aperta um botão. O problema é que eu tenho que ler esse primeiro ListCtrl de fora para obter o item que está focado. Quando eu faço isso na primeira vez, de boa, o ruim é quanto clico sem selecionar nada pela segunda vez.

**Imagens**

Quando eu clico em na série, as disciplinas aparecem, daí eu tenho que clicar no disciplina antes de tentar adicionar, até aí tudo bem.

[image: Primeira imagem]

Quando eu clico em adicionar, a disciplina vai pro outro lado... blz.

[image: Segunda imagem]

Mas quando eu clico novamente em adicionar a disciplina, mesmo sem selecionar nada, ele adiciona a que estava no lugar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código**

Quando eu clico no botão, essa função é chamada, e *lstDisciplinasPadroes* indica a tabela do lado esquerdo e *self.lstDisciplinasEscolhidas* as do lado direito:

```
def adicionar_disciplina(self, event):
    n_disciplina = self.lstDisciplinasPadroes.GetFocusedItem()

    if not self.lstDisciplinasPadroes.IsSelected(n_disciplina):
        event.Skip()

    if 0 <= n_disciplina:
        #### INICIO ADICIONA NAS ESCOLHIDAS ####
        abreviacao = self.lstDisciplinasPadroes.GetItem(n_disciplina, 0).GetText()
        nomeDisciplina = self.lstDisciplinasPadroes.GetItem(n_disciplina, 1).GetText()
        nomeProfessor = self.lstDisciplinasPadroes.GetItem(n_disciplina, 2).GetText()

        numeroDisciplinasEscolhidas = self.lstDisciplinasEscolhidas.GetItemCount()

        self.lstDisciplinasEscolhidas.InsertItem(numeroDisciplinasEscolhidas, abreviacao)
        self.lstDisciplinasEscolhidas.SetItem(numeroDisciplinasEscolhidas, 1, nomeDisciplina)
        self.lstDisciplinasEscolhidas.SetItem(numeroDisciplinasEscolhidas, 2, nomeProfessor)
        #### FIM ADICIONA NAS ESCOLHIDAS ####

        #### INICIO REMOVE PADROES ####
        self.lstDisciplinasPadroes.DeleteItem(n_disciplina)
        #### FIM REMOVE PADROES ####

        self.disciplinasPorTurma[self.turma].update({abreviacao: [nomeDisciplina, nomeProfessor]})
    else:
        event.Skip()
```

Notas:

- Aparentemente, essa variável *n_disciplina* é interna da função e não armazena seu valor em nenhum outro lugar.
- Esse primeiro pequeno if eu adicionei agora pouco para tentar responder a minha própria pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código remove todas as seleções:

```
for x in xrange(0, self.lstDisciplinasPadroes.GetItemCount(), 1):
    self.lstDisciplinasPadroes.Select(x, on=0)
```